# Grouping Variables With Select in r

Tags: r, select, dplyr, grouping

I am just getting started with R and dplyr(and coding in general), and I am trying to use tools from the "R for Data Science" text to use R to look at the data from a wastewater system at a local brewery which as at the link provided [Link to Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UrOUoNTYyjlEsl7RyFe-FbeAyc9_F9bQsp3F_pr72LI/edit?usp=sharing.)

Early into the process I was just trying to get a table to summarize the inflow characteristics but no matter what I do, when I use **select()** I simply get all of my data returned instead of the columns I wanted, along with a warning about adding missing grouping variables.

This warning is something I never encountered when using the tidyverse data, and I am wondering if I am doing some fundamental thing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

```r
library(Tidyverse)
Results <- read_csv("Results Table.csv")
Results <- as_tibble(Results)

Inlet_group <- group_by(Results, 'Sample Set', I_Date)

Inlet_Av <- summarise(Inlet_group, 
                      Ave_pH = mean(I_pH, na.rm = T),
                      Ave_Conductivity = mean(I_Conductivity, na.rm = T),
                      Ave_Turbidity_NTU = mean(I_Turbidity_NTU, na.rm = T),
                      Ave_BOD_mgL = mean(I_BOD_mgL, na.rm = T),
                      Ave_TSS_mgL = mean(I_TSS_mgL, na.rm = T),
                      Ave_Ammonia_mgL = mean(I_Ammonia_mgL, na.rm = T),
                      Ave_NitrateNitrite_mgL = mean(I_NitrateNitrite_mgL, na.rm = T),
                      Ave_OG_mgL = mean(I_OG_mgL, na.rm = T))

ungroup(Inlet_Av)

Inlet_Av <- select(Inlet_Av, Ave_pH:Ave_OG_mgL)

Inlet_AVE
```

Comment: `tidyverse` is not capitalized; `group_by` generally doesn't take things that are strings; the result of `ungroup` needs to be assigned to a variable; `Inlet_Av` != `Inlet_AVE`. Also, check out `summarise_all`/`summarise_at` to save yourself a lot of typing.

Comment: Thank you! This is clearly going to be a steep learning curve for me

Comment: Eh, most of it is effectively typos.